# codeception unable to call a function defined in acceptancetester.php from a cest file

Tags: php, codeception

Hi I am new to codeception,
Was trying to call a function defined in AcceptanceTester.php from a Cest.
But getting the error return **Call to undefined function demoInjection()**.

Below is my function defination and calling function

```
public function demoInjection($aLinkText,$sLinkName)
{
    $I= $this;

    for($z=0;$z<=Count($aLinkText);$z++)
    {
        if ($aLinkText[$z] = $sLinkName){
                $I->Click($aLinkText[$z]);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Calling function

```
public function checkGrabmultiple(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $I->click('Online Games');
    $aLinkText = $I->grabMultiple("//div[@class='col']",'class');
    $LinkName = 'Gold Spinner';
    $I->debug(demoInjection($aLinkText,$sLinkName));
}
```

Comment: it should be `$this->demoInjection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to call a helper method is

```
$I->demoInjection($aLinkText,$sLinkName);
```

because helper method belongs to the Tester and not to the Cest class.

Comment: In that case the error should be different - it should say that the method is undefined.

Comment: it is giving the same error as i mentioned above "Call to undefined function demoInjection()"

Comment: it was just issue with Version 2.1.

Comment: As I upgraded to 2.2,it worked perfectly.Thanks A lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending of your version of codeception, you might have to run

```
 php codecept.phar build
```

after making changes to AcceptanceTester.php.

On later version this is run before executing testes, but you can disable it.

This command ceates a function with your new function/step's name in AcceptanceTesterActions.php.
This will allow codecetion to use your new function in the form of

> $I->demoInjection($aLinkText,$sLinkName);

Good luck and happy testing!!

Comment: I tried the same and AcceptanceTesterAction.php is also generated, but there is no step name in it with the function which i have created in AceptanceTester.php.

Comment: 1. What version of codeception are you using?  (php codecept.phar -V)
2. Can you give me the output of "php codecept.phar build"

Comment: here is the output for php codecept.phar build   
Building Actor classes for suites: acceptance, functional, unit
 -> AcceptanceTesterActions.php generated successfully. 0 methods added
\AcceptanceTester includes modules: WebDriver, \Helper\Acceptance
 -> FunctionalTesterActions.php generated successfully. 0 methods added
\FunctionalTester includes modules: \Helper\Functional
 -> UnitTesterActions.php generated successfully. 0 methods added
\UnitTester includes modules: Asserts, \Helper\Unit